# How to solve insecure warning after google chrome upgraded to 86

Tags: google-chrome, cakephp, cakephp-3.6

I am facing one issue on my CakePHP project. I have SSL installed into my project and it was working properly earlier. But the problem started with all the forms after google chrome upgraded to `86 stable`. It is started giving insecured warning message while submitting any form even for login form. This is happening in google chrome only.

I had done some research on this and saw updated google chrome browser added another layer of security for users. And then I did some research on solving the issue and the only thing I got it to add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` into my website header. I did this but still the result is same.
I also got some suggestion to check mixed content issue aslo need to check if anything loaded over http. I had checked and there is noting loading from `http`.

Another thing is, my website is running from `https://www` and while insecure warning is showing the `url` become `http://www`

Comment: cakephp version?

Comment: 3.6 is the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute path.

```
https://something.com/foo
```

Something similar was posted here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1158169#c23

**Try:**

```
$this->redirect("/action/dosomething");
↓
$this->redirect("//" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/action/dosomething");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to force https @ .htaccess like

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or create Middleware to handle request (if host === 'http', redirect to https)

- [create Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/middleware.html#creating-middleware)
- [How to interact with request](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/middleware.html#interacting-with-requests)